# Auto increment a invoice number using Google sheets formula

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have an invoice numbering in the format

```
SMGS/20-21/COU-07
SMGS/20-21/COU-08
SMGS/20-21/COU-09
SMGS/20-21/COU-10
SMGS/20-21/COU-11
```

When my cell A7 has `SMGS/20-21/COU-11`, how do I generate the next number as `SMGS/20-21/COU-12` in B7 cell using Google Sheets formula?
Where the 20-21 year is also auto generated. After March 31, the year shall become 21-22.

I have tried with `=split(B4,"-")`

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())>3,YEAR(TODAY())&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(TODAY())+1,2),YEAR(TODAY())-1&"-"& RIGHT(YEAR(TODAY()),2))
```

this displays 2020-21, But I need 20-21 .

Comment: Numbering after march starts from ```01``` or continues? Can numbering exceed 99?

Comment: Yes number exceed 99.. the below formula doesn't work after 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A8** enter:

```
=left(A7,15) & right(A7,2)+1
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In **A8** enter:

```
=left(A7,15) & mid(A7,16,99)+1
```

and copy downward!

[image]

Comment: This won't work after 99... Could you help me to adjust the formula pls

Comment: @CodeGuy  Check back tomorrow!

Comment: @CodeGuy  See my **EDIT#1**